# Laravel Notification Want to use view html in notification blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-notification

I'm using Laravel version 5.7.20 to build a custom markdown template. The template is copied from `/resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`
which is generated after issuing the command `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications`.

The following works which displays HTML:

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->line(new HtmlString('The <strong>introduction</strong> to the notification.'))
    ->line('The <strong>introduction</strong> to the notification.')
    ->line(new HtmlString('Due Date: <strong>' . Carbon::parse($this->info->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i') . '</strong>'))
    ->line('Due Date: <strong>' . Carbon::parse($this->info->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i') . '</strong>')
    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'));
```

[image]

This is not working. Which is using my own markdown

```
return (new MailMessage)
            ->line(new HtmlString('The <strong>introduction</strong> to the notification.'))
            ->line('The <strong>introduction</strong> to the notification.')
            ->line(new HtmlString('Due Date: <strong>' . Carbon::parse($this->info->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i').'</strong>'))
            ->line('Due Date: <strong>' . Carbon::parse($this->info->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i').'</strong>')
            ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
            ->markdown('mail.notification.permission');
```

[image]

my mail.notification.permission file is copy exactly from `laravel-project/resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php`

I think I need **view** not a **markdown**. But I change `->view('mail.notification.permission');` I got error `No hint path defined for [mail]. (View: /Users/shiro/Sites/laravel-project/resources/views/mail/notification/permission.blade.php)`

which file I should copy in order for me using html, not the markup format.

I haven't see any solution in notification use ->view instead of ->markdown. Or what is the correct flow to display html in notification email?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Are you wanting to get the html tags to work that are coming out as text? Or are you wanting to just use a template file instead of creating a `MailMessage` object?

Comment: I want my notification blade template able to display the correct html not the htmlspecialchars or encoded version. As you can see, the html table show the source code, and the bold text not display, it changed to tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I found out the error.

If want to use `->view()`, the blade template can't use `@component('mail::message')`, it have to build with fresh blade layout (Build you own view like normal page). Then you will not get `No hint path defined for [mail]` error.

Laravel Notification Mark Up a lot to learn their syntax and their eco system. It is great for those who want a simple notification. But if you want custom page, I would suggest to use `view()`.

I share my layout blade file which I copy after I send out from mark down. The content part you have your own logic.

```
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('New Invoice')
            ->view( 'mail.notification.custom_invoice', ['invoice' => $this->invoice]);
    {
```

`email_layout.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #f5f8fa; color: #74787E; height: 100%; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0; -moz-hyphens: auto; -ms-word-break: break-all; width: 100% !important; -webkit-hyphens: auto; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; word-break: break-word;">
<style>
    @media  only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .inner-body {
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        .footer {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }

    @media  only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .button {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
</style>

<table class="wrapper" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #f5f8fa; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <table class="content" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="header" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 25px 0; text-align: center;">
                        <a href="{{ url('/') }}" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #bbbfc3; font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;">
                            {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <!-- Email Body -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="body" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEFF2; border-top: 1px solid #EDEFF2; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 100%;">
                        <table class="inner-body" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #FFFFFF; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 570px; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px;">
                            <!-- Body content -->
                            <tr>
                                <td class="content-cell" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 35px;">
                                    @yield('content')
                                    <p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Regards,<br>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</p>
                                    @yield('subcopy')
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box;">
                        <table class="footer" align="center" width="570" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; width: 570px; -premailer-cellpadding: 0; -premailer-cellspacing: 0; -premailer-width: 570px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="content-cell" align="center" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 35px;">
                                    <p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; color: #AEAEAE; font-size: 12px; text-align: center;">© {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}. All rights reserved.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im also faced with this problem: **HTML tags was outputted as a plain text** in Laravel notification emails (HTML not show/works).

First of all:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Laravel will put mail and notification templates to `resources/views/vendor/mail` and `resources/views/vendor/notifications`

The problem was in my perfectionism: i edited HTML blade file templates/layouts and **added indents** there like usual HTML file. **Do not do it!**